# FFMPEG color key overlay. audio output not working after conversion

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

ffmpeg -i hollywood.webm -i chroma.mp4 -filter_complex [1:v]colorkey=0x000000:0.3:0.2[ckout];[0:v][ckout]overlay[out] -map [out] test1.mp4

If you dont know the answer would appreaciate to have the map documentations sent to me, didnt find it

this is what  been trying t do where chroma is the overlay video that also has audio and hollywood is the background video with also audio, the output image wise is good but the -map section is probably not going that well.

Comment: You forgot to map the audio stream, change the end of that command to `-map [out] -map 0:a test1.mp4` (assuming the first video has the audio)

Comment: Really appreciate it DID get the audio of the first video. Is it possible to get the audio of the second one too ? te chroma key audio ? REALLY appreciated your help

Comment: is there a way of giving points to your answer ?

Comment: It's almost a typo, so it's best dealt with by a comment, I'm sure there are existing answers that cover it. To get the audio of the second video simply use `-map 1:a`

Comment: I just realised that you may have been asking to merge the two audio tracks. Take a look a the `amerge` filter. Input [0:a][1:a] output [aud] then remember to map [aud]